# How to get dat.gui controller type?

Tags: javascript, types, controller, dat.gui

I have a dat.gui instance with a number of controllers. I can get a list of them with `gui.__controllers`, but I don't see any property on them that shows their type (dropdown, slider, color picker, etc).

Is there any way to get their type, maybe through the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, there doesn't seem to be a type property which states the type of controller. However you do obviously already know what the types are as you define them in the dat.GUI property object (i.e. a boolean value is a checkbox etc.).

You can though determine the type of controller as can be seen in the following codepen:

http://codepen.io/BenSmith/pen/rHpzC

See the debug console for the list of controller types as they appear on screen.

The key part of the code to determine the type is:

```
for (var i in gui.__controllers) {

 var controller = gui.__controllers[i];

 switch(controller.__li.className){
  case 'cr string':
    if (controller.__select != null) {
      console.log('dropdown');
    }
    else {
      console.log('input');
    }
    break;
  case 'cr number has-slider':
    console.log('slider');
    break;
  case 'cr boolean':
    console.log('checkbox');
    break;
  case 'cr object color':
    console.log('color picker'); 
    break;
  default:
    console.log('Unrecognized controller!')
  }  
}
```